# Giving different padding inline spans

Tags: html, css

I have three spans inlined 2 image, and one text. text is between two images. So I am trying put proper height differently. So I gave class differently. But padding is not work. And also I want to put image2 right corner.

the display is like [image: this]

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt>
       <span class="image"><img src="img/question-blue.png"></span>
        <span class="text">Text Text</span>
        <span class="image2"><img src="img/open-blue-big.png"></span>
    </dt>       
</dl>
```

My css on span classes don't work?

```
dd {
    margin: 0;
}

dl.accordion {
    font-family: helvetica Neue; 
    width:100%;
    margin:20px auto 30px; 
    font-size:16px;
}

dl.accordion dt {
    border-bottom:1px solid #EEE; 
    height:auto; 
    text-indent:10px; 
    line-height:40px; 
    color:#333; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    cursor:pointer;}
dl.accordion dt.open {
    background:url(../img/close.png) 97% center no-repeat,-moz-linear-gradient(top, #C6F0FE, #27BCF9);
    background:url(../img/close.png) 97% center no-repeat,-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#C6F0FE), to(#27BCF9));}
dl.accordion dd { 
    background:#FFF; 
    padding:10px; 
    line-height:1.5; 
    display:none;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.image2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help *("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. - We cannot tell you what's wrong with your CSS if we cannot see it!

Comment: sorry mate, I updated the question. @TylerRoper

Comment: You need to clarify your question. You have padding on top and bottom of your text spans and don't have it on your image spans, exactly like your CSS indicates you should. What is the problem?

Comment: I update the question and put an image to explain. I am giving padding just text because text is look downside. But my padding doesnt't work to put it middle of the line. Also, image2 button is doesnt go to rigt corner! @ecg8

Comment: So, your issue isn't about padding. The issue is that you want to vertically align the text in the middle of the span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

An element with `display: flex` will align its `display: block` children side by side. You can use [`align-items: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to center them vertically, and [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to spread them out evenly with space between.

If you want your text to be left-aligned as well, you can set it to `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
dt {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

dt > span {
    display: block;
}

dt > span.text { flex-grow: 1; padding-left: 10px; }
```

```html
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt>
        <span class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50"></span>
        <span class="text">Text Text</span>
        <span class="image2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50"></span>
    </dt>       
</dl>
```

Here is a visual representation of what the  above is doing:

```css
dt {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

dt>span {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

dt>span.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="accordion">
  <dt>
    <span class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50"></span>
    <span class="text">This div's width will grow to fill the space because of "flex-grow: 1"</span>
    <span class="image2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50"></span>
  </dt>
</dl>
```

Comment: it s close perfect but. But text is need to next to the first pic. not middle of two image.

Comment: @Potti Updated!

Comment: @Potti Not a problem. For completeness, I've also added a visual representation. It helps to see an example with borders sometimes to see what's actually going on.

Comment: I have one last question for you! Having this issue if there is one image. https://imgur.com/a/TY4tPr8 Sorry for burden.

Comment: Can you put your code for that example in a JSFiddle? I can't replicate the issue. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/r0jn8mve/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r0jn8mve/2/ the first one is question and the second is answer.

Comment: @Potti If you look at the CSS, you'll see that I've only applied the styles to `dt`, and to `dt > ...` (immediate children of `dt`). Therefore none of the CSS will apply to `dd` or `dd > ...` elements. If you need to apply it to `dd` too, then try this: http://jsfiddle.net/r0jn8mve/3/